Laravel 11 Application Running in Subdirectory on IIS 10 - 404 Error and Blank Page
I am running two Laravel applications on the same IIS 10 server. The first application is Laravel 10, and it is working correctly. I am having trouble with a second Laravel 11 application that is running in a subdirectory and encountering issues with routing.
Problem:
The second Laravel 11 application is located in the new-app subdirectory of my domain (e.g., www.maydomain.com/new-app). Although the application runs correctly when accessed directly through its own URL, navigating to routes under the subdirectory (e.g., www.maydomain.com/new-app/test) results in a 404 error or a blank page.
Configuration Details:

IIS Configuration (web.config for Laravel 11 Application in new-app):

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!-- Remove trailing slash -->
                <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
                </rule>

                <!-- Rewrite requests to subdirectory "new-app" -->
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^new-app/(.*)$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <!-- If the request is not a directory or a file -->
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/new-app/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>


.env Configuration for Laravel 11 Application:

APP_URL=http://www.maydomain.com/new-app
APP_DEBUG=true



Laravel Routes (routes/web.php):

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/test/{id}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Issue Details:

Error: When accessing http://www.maydomain.com/new-app/test, I receive a 404 error or sometimes a blank page.
Logs: No logs are created in storage/logs for the Laravel application. Error details are not visible in IIS.
Direct Access: Accessing http://www.maydomain.com/new-app/index.php works, indicating that the Laravel app is functioning when accessed directly.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified web.config syntax and updated rewrite rules.
Checked file permissions and ensured that index.php is present in the public directory.
Updated .env file to set APP_URL.
Cleared Laravel caches (php artisan config:clear, php artisan route:clear, php artisan view:clear, php artisan cache:clear).
Enabled detailed error reporting in IIS.
Created a simple route to test if Laravel handles requests.

Questions:

Are there additional IIS configuration settings needed for running Laravel in a subdirectory?
Could there be issues with Laravel routing when served from a subdirectory?
Are there any other troubleshooting steps or configurations I might be missing?

Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Laravel must be run at the root path of the domain.

Check If any other subdirectory with same name of your route in public folder which will cause 404.
